# CLIPS vs NN to create a chatbot

Tags: neural-network, chatbot, clips

I am introduced to CLIPS for the first time and trying to understand if it is a better way to implement a chat bot. From what I understand till now, it is widely used to create expert systems and is entirely rule based.
I have tried using NN to create a conversational engine, but it fails miserably even for simple variations of training data, which can be handled very easily with rules.

Now rules can be written in any language.
What are the advantages of CLIPS over any other language?

EDIT 1:
The answers suggest that CLIPS is a good choice as it uses a pattern matching algorithm. However, with little experimentation I did with CLIPS, I could not see as to why declaring rules, that fire up when LHS fact of rule is activated, is a better approach. Let me give an example:

Suppose I want to create a chat bot that answers result of a student.

```
BOT: What are you looking for?
      1. grade
      2. subjects
USER: grade
BOT:  Enter stream name.
USER: electrical
BOT:  Enter student name
USER: john
BOT:  grade in electrical for john is 56%
```

This is the CLIPS script I wrote for this:

```
(defrule main-intent
(initial-fact)
=>
(printout t"What are you looking for?
1. grade
2. subjects
")
(assert(why))
(assert(intent (read)))
)

;;;======================================================
(defrule grade-intent
(intent grade)
=>
(printout t"Enter stream name."crlf)
(bind ?stream (read))
(assert (stream-name ?stream))) ;;;There should be stream name validator here

;;;======================================================
(defrule stream-name
(stream-name ?stream)
=>
(printout t "Enter student name "crlf)
(bind ?user (read))
(assert (user-name ?stream ?user))) ;;;There should be student name validator here

;;;======================================================
(defrule user-name-rule
(user-name ?stream ?user)
=>
(printout t"grade in " ?stream " for " ?user " is 56%" crlf)
(bind ?grade 60)
(assert(grade-is ?grade)))
;;;======================================================


(defrule explanation
(why)
=>
(printout t "==============================" crlf)
(retract 0)
(facts)
(printout t "==============================" crlf)
)
```

On the other hand, I have a rule based conversational engine in python where I have trained a NLP model to extract intent and entity from user query. I use a configuration file like below to define dialouge flow:

```
ask_stream:
    call_python_fn: "validate_stream" # python routine that check against DB if stream exist. Returns value valid/invalid
    properties:
      prompt: "Enter stream name"
    transitions:
        valid: "ask_user" # if return value is valid, goto next state, ask_user
        invalid: "ask_stream" # else again ask for correct stream name

ask_user:
    component: "validate_user" # python routine that check against DB if student exist. Returns value valid/invalid
    properties:
      prompt: "Enter student name"
    transitions:
        valid: "hit_grade_api" # if return value is valid, goto next state
        invalid: "ask_user" # else again ask user

hit_grade_api:
    component: "grade_api" # python routine that hits an API to fetch grades
    properties:
      variable: "grade"
      prompt: "grade in"+%stream+"for"+%user+" is "+%grade
```

So, if my flow changes, say the bot needs student's Roll No., I have to add an extra node in my python config file to ask for Roll No., and similarly I have to add a new rule in CLIPS. So what is the advantage of CLIPS then?

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 3):

CLIPS is an implementation of the [RETE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) algorithm. RETE is one of the most effective algorithm for implementing expert systems as it minimizes the amount of pattern matching required by inference processes.

Implementing a rule engine is a fairly simple task at first. Nevertheless, as soon as the complexity increases, the problem suddenly reveals its exponential nature and performance become a major concern.

If your chatbot remains simple enough, you might not see immediate benefits adopting CLIPS. Nevertheless, CLIPS is the tool of choice if you want to ensure good scalability when the amount and complexity of user interaction  increases.

Another reason to try CLIPS is its extensive [documentation](http://www.clipsrules.net/Documentation.html) which is a very good starting point for people which want to learn Artificial Intelligence beyond the statistical-based solutions so popular nowadays.

Lastly, adopting an existing rule-based language instead or rolling your own will free yourself from a lot of maintenance. Thus letting you focus on what really matters which are the rules and the underlying platform.

CLIPS is also well supported on Python via its bindings (the older [pyclips](https://github.com/almostearthling/pyclips) and the newer [clipspy](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy)). You can easily extend the CLIPS language via embedding Python code within ([example](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest#embedding-python)). This allows you to port any Python library into CLIPS and use it straight away.

Comment: what would you recommend..pyclips or clipspy?

Comment: As I am the developer of clipspy, my opinion might be slightly biased. You can see [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/discussion/776945/thread/e001210c/) discussion where I explain the main differences between the two libraries.

Comment: is it possible to load a .clp file in clipspy and then run it via python

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at prior art to see if it's applicable to what you're trying to do. If you search for "eliza source code" you'll find implementations of this chatbot in multiple languages (including a java version at https://github.com/codeanticode/eliza). These programs use scripts which make it easier to incrementally increase the responses that can be handled. Here's a portion of the script for Eliza:

```
key: my 2
  decomp: $ * my *
    reasmb: Lets discuss further why your (2).
    reasmb: Earlier you said your (2).
    reasmb: But your (2).
    reasmb: Does that have anything to do with the fact that your (2) ?
  decomp: * my* @family *
    reasmb: Tell me more about your family.
    reasmb: Who else in your family (4) ?
    reasmb: Your (3) ?
    reasmb: What else comes to mind when you think of your (3) ?
  decomp: * my *
    reasmb: Your (2) ?
    reasmb: Why do you say your (2) ?
    reasmb: Does that suggest anything else which belongs to you ?
    reasmb: Is it important that your (2) ?
```

If you're implementing your chatbot from scratch, a language that supports pattern matching such as CLIPS would be a natural fit for matching these scripts to responses from the user.

Comment: I read about Eliza and found that it is an AI Program that simulates the behavior of a therapist. It basically answers the question with a question. But I want to create a chatbot that replaces a web applications and gives the user exactly what he asked for. It will need to hit an API to fetch the correct value. To hit the API, it needs to pass arguments, which it obbtains from user by asking correct questions. Now I can write rules that for API1(intent1) ask arg1,arg2(entities) and for API2(intent2) ask arg2,arg3(entities). So, is there any advantage of using CLIPS for writing these rules?

Comment: The point of using a declarative programming language is to separate the declarative knowledge (what you want done) from the engine (the code that processes the knowledge). If your knowledge is declarative in nature, then you can avoid having to write the engine by using a declarative programming language. The configuration file in the example in your question is declarative knowledge and you have a specialized engine for processing it, so it's unlikely that you're going to see much benefit using a more generalized engine such as CLIPS.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of advantages of CLIPS.

Sure, you could use any turing complete language to achieve the same goal,
but do you want to create a flowchart and hard coded it in a language. I guess not. A small change in your logic could mean substantial alterations in you control flow.

The beauty lies in the rule-centric approach. You have an if-then relation with a few additional concepts like salience on top. So, if the logic changes, you only have to alter a few rules and there you go.
And because of the rete-algorithm CLIPS it is - despite its abstract concept - very fast.

But of course it is limited by the number of rules you implement. In your case, rules inherently limit the complexity of a chat. But it's totally deterministic. So you know what you will get with a certain input.
Sure, a trained neural network is also deterministic, but as of now, you're not really able to reason about it. You don't know the why... why does the NN behaves as it behaves?

In principle one would guess, a NN would generalize better with less effort. But for now, I wouldn't say so. You need enough data and I guess you lack the needed amount by orders of magnitude. Also, a NN can be played easily. Think of Microsoft's Twitter bot TAY. And additionally, you don't have the computing power to train a NN that performs at a level you want it to perform.

For a chatbot I would go with CLIPS. I think you get the most bang out of your buck. You will have to live with limitations, but that's okay. You can always extend your set of rules until you are satisfied. And for a beginner it's better because you are able to reenact what it is doing.

Comment: Yes you are right that I do not have sufficient data to train NN. But I am still not clear why clips is better. If I have to "change a few rules" that means I'll have to make "substantial alterations" like in any other language.